# Pivoting in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am very new to SSRS/SQL

I have been cracking my head over this but still can't find a solution.
I would like to present it in a pivot kind of way.

This is what I have:

```
Cust.Type | CUSTDOC    | Cr.Date   | Ln.Num | Qty | Due.Date
Local     | CORD0001   | 14-May-14 |   8    | 33  | 16-May-14
Local     | CDSP0001   | 15-May-14 |   5    | 25  | 16-May-14
Local     | CINV0001   | 16-May-14 |   5    | 25  | 16-May-14
Local     | CDSP0001/1 | 19-May-14 |   2    | 5   | 19-May-14
Local     | CINV0001/1 | 19-May-14 |   2    | 5   | 19-May-14
Local     | CDSP0001/2 | 25-May-14 |   1    | 3   | 25-May-14
Local     | CINV0001/2 | 25-May-14 |   1    | 3   | 25-May-14
Local     | SINV2234   |
Local     | CRED8384   |
Int       | CORD0002   | 30-Jun-14 |   5    |  15 | 12-Jul-14
Int       | CDSP0002   | 11-Jul-14 |   5    |  15 | 12-Jul-14
```

I would like to arrange it by order number

```
Cust.Type | Order Number | Order.Date | Order.Due | C.Disp   | Disp.Due  |  etc.
Local     | 0001         | 14-May-14  | 16-May-14 | 15-May-14| 16-May-14 |  etc.
```

I am using SSRS2012 Express.

Can someone give me a hand here?

Thanks
H

Answer (score 0):

You can use a matrix for Pivoting. this article is a good resource for you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157334(v=sql.100).aspx